# The name 'General' does not exist in the current context. in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, class

I've searched and tried a lot to solve this small problem. the ASP.NET problem is
"**The name 'General' does not exist in the current context.**"
[General] is a class which contains two functions.
Please how to solve it.
I am beginner in programming

this is the class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace B5CS
{
public class General
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        string strConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        return con;
    }

    public static DataTable GetDataTable(string sql,SqlConnection con)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
}}
```

here is where I want to use the class "General", in a master page

```
private void LoadLeftMenu()
{
    SqlConnection con = General.GetConnetion();
    string sql = "select fld_MenuID,fld_MenuName from tbl_Menus order by fld_MenuName";
    DataTable dt = General.GetDataTable(sql, con);
    this.DataList1.DataSource = dt;
    this.DataList1.DataBind();}}
```

Comment: Show is some code.  Start with the class and the code that is producing that error.

Comment: the error is under the word General in the site.master (my masterpage)

Comment: General.GetConnetion();
General.GetDataTable(sql, con);

Comment: What namespace does your `LoadLeftMenu` exist in? And what namespaces do you reference in your using statements at the top of that file? By the way, you really need to make sure that you properly code for things that implement IDisposable. They should be in a `using` block or they should have `Dispose` method called in a `finally` block to make sure they get closed and free up unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 1):

General class is public so should be accessible anywhere in the code. However class/namespace containing the method LoadLeftMenu() is unable to access the General class.

1. Please check if LoadLeftMenu() method containing namespace == B5CS, else include it to the top of your LoadLeftmenu() class code i.e. "using [Namespace]" according to your project code.
2. Also trying checking if your classes are private and hence not accessible. For testing purposes, change them to protected or public and latter change back to suit your project needs.

Comment: the namespace isn't craeted automatically in the project
I had to add it manually and I guess the problem is here
I need to solve the problem ASAP the deadlock in Sunday
Can I uploaded somewhere so that you can see my website

Comment: Sure. Will take a look. Upload it and send me the link. Try one of these [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/top-5-places-to-share-code-quickly/)